# C command line arguments in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a C console application, and I want to parse command line arguments in visual studio while debugging, I know how to do it in eclipse but can't find this option in visual studio. So where can I find this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project, go to:

> Project->*Project name* Properties

alternately hit Alt+F7, or, in solution explorer, right click on your project and choose "properties" from the drop down menu.

then, go to:

> Configuration Properties->Debugging

You can pass command line arguments in on the line that says `Command Arguments`

Comment: @Martin Beckett - I know *somebody* out there would appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the Debug tab on the project properties. There will be an option for the command line arguments.  The exact position varies according to the version you're using and you don't say which version you have (otherwise I could look and list the name/tab/etc verbatim).